# Hipe Not Found in Erlang R18

Tags: compilation, erlang, erlang-shell, hipe

When I try to use Hipe to compile a module from the Erlang shell, I get:

```
3> hipe:c(erlangmodules2,[native]).
** exception error: undefined function hipe:c/2
4> hipe:help().
** exception error: undefined function hipe:help/0
```

Isn't Hipe part of standard Erlang? I'm running R18 from Eshell V7.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install `erlang-base-hipe` package for that.

Comment: That worked. That piece of essential information was missing from [Learn You Some Erlang for Great Good - Modules](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/modules), thus the confusion.

Comment: Hipe is part of the standard release so there is generally no need to mention it. It is Ubuntu which doesn't give you everything which means you have to know these things. Blame them. Everything referenced in LYSE is part of the standard release.

Comment: There is no need to blame anyone. Its just the way it works. There are good reasons for them to make it into separate package.